# Как сделать отступ первой строки при помощи python из текстового файла в docx в каждом абзаце?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

[image: Отступ первой строки]

Есть текст для примера (text.txt):

> Существуют две основные трактовки понятия «текст»: имманентная
> (расширенная, философски нагруженная) и репрезентативная (более
> частная). Имманентный подход подразумевает отношение к тексту как к
> автономной реальности, нацеленность на выявление его внутренней
> структуры. Репрезентативный — рассмотрение текста как особой формы
> представления информации о внешней тексту действительности.
>
> В лингвистике термин «текст» используется в широком значении, включая
> и образцы устной речи. Восприятие текста изучается в рамках
> лингвистики текста и психолингвистики. Так, например, И. Р. Гальперин
> определяет текст следующим образом: «Это письменное сообщение,
> объективированное в виде письменного документа, состоящее из ряда
> высказываний, объединённых разными типами лексической, грамматической
> и логической связи, имеющее определённый модальный характер,
> прагматическую установку и соответственно литературно обработанное».

У меня получилось только сделать отступ первого абзаца.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt, RGBColor
from docx.enum.text import WD_UNDERLINE
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH 
from docx.enum.section import WD_SECTION, WD_ORIENT
from docx.shared import Mm
# создание документа
doc = Document()
section = doc.sections[0]
section.page_height = Mm(297)
section.page_width = Mm(210)
section.left_margin = Mm(23.5)
section.right_margin = Mm(23.5)
section.top_margin = Mm(20)
section.bottom_margin = Mm(20)
section.header_distance = Mm(0)
section.footer_distance = Mm(0)
# задаем стиль текста по умолчанию
style = doc.styles['Normal']
style.font.name = 'Times New Roman'
style.font.size = Pt(14)
# Text
my_file = open('text.txt', 'r')

data = my_file.read()
# Добавляем абзац
p = doc.add_paragraph(data)
# выравниваем абзац по ширине
p.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.JUSTIFY
# получаем объект форматирования
fmt = p.paragraph_format
# Форматируем:
# отступ слева в мм
fmt.first_line_indent = Mm(15)
# отступ сверху в мм 
fmt.space_before = Mm(20)
# отступ снизу в мм
fmt.space_after = Mm(10)

doc.save('test.docx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере - весь текст из файла является одним абзацем с точки зрения форматирования. Необходимо разделить файл по переносам строки, и создать абзацы для каждого такого элемента. Как-то так:

```py
...
# Text
my_file = open('text.txt', 'r')

for data in my_file.read().split('\n'):
    # Добавляем абзац
    p = doc.add_paragraph(data)
    # выравниваем абзац по ширине
    p.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.JUSTIFY
    # получаем объект форматирования
    fmt = p.paragraph_format
    # Форматируем:
    # отступ слева в мм
    fmt.first_line_indent = Mm(15)
    # отступ сверху в мм
    fmt.space_before = Mm(20)
    # отступ снизу в мм
    fmt.space_after = Mm(10)

    doc.save('test.docx')
```